# Is it ok to request for a cubicle change to be closer to your team members?

Tags: offices, office-layout, collaboration

Today I emailed my supervisor to request for a cubical change. I’m currently not sitting close to anyone in my team which makes collaboration difficult. I thought it was a good idea to move closer to my team members. One guy in my team didn’t seem happy with my request. Is this not a good idea?

Comment: why is he unhappy about you moving?

Comment: Why are you sitting "far" away from your team to begin with?

Comment: Of course it is ok. Especially  if you explain it in terms of benefit to the project, rather than yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Yes sitting with your team can improve communication and is generally a good idea.

You'd have to ask the guy on your team why he was unhappy but it could be many things e.g.

- you would be moving to a better desk than him, or one that he was hoping to have for himself
- moving your desk might mean rearranging other desks including his, i.e. create short-term hassle for him
- he thinks that you interrupt him too much already, or micro-manage him, and is worried that this will get worse when you're closer
- your office is quiet and he thinks that having more people around would add to the noise and disruptions in general

or maybe you're mistaken and he wasn't really unhappy about that.

But we can only speculate. If you're not comfortable asking him directly then maybe ask someone else on the team that you get on with well if they know why he was upset.

Comment: he also may be unhappy if the person who has to give up the seat is well liked in that group or a personal friend he likes to sit / work with.

Answer (score 5):

It is perfectly fine to ask for this.

Usually employers automatically arrange seatings with teamwork in mind.

Depending on the company / industry change of seating arrangements may even happen every time a new team is put together for a certain project.